# Strtok + If Statement

Tags: c, if-statement, strtok

im new in here and im having a headache with my program,the thing is that i need to get a input from the keyboard and then separate it using strtok but have to separate the tokens using 4 diferent cases and in each case i need to print the result and save it to a string like this:

```
input String : Label Instruction #50,Y; Label <with>
```

and the output should look like this:

```
Label: Label
Instruction: Instruction
Character [1]: #50
Character [2]: Y
Comentaries: Label <with>
```

also it has to be able to reconize if a instruction is missed like this:

```
Input String: adda
Output String
Label: -----
Instruction: adda
Character 1: -----
Comentaries: -----
```

My code can accept the first and correct instruction but when i type a incorrect one like in the second input it ignores it and continue like the first atempt just ading  sometimes,i have tryed to use if to be able to separate each token with its delimeter but everitime i compile it it ignores the if statement no matter what argument i gave it i dont know what else to do
Heres my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {     char word[256];
    fgets(word,256,stdin);
char *token;
while (token != NULL){
            char delimiter[]="\n , ;";
            token=strtok (word,delimiter);
            //if(token != "\n")            //{
            //char delimiter[]="\n , ;";
//token=strtok (word,delimiter);
//if (delimiter != " "||"\t" || "_")
            printf("Label \"%s\"\n", token);
token = strtok (NULL, "\n , ;");   //(NULL, "_,.-")//}
            //token=strtok (word,delimiter);            //}
//printf("Label ----------\n");
if (delimiter != "\n"||"\t")//{
            printf("Instruction \"%s\"\n", token);
token = strtok (NULL, "\n , ;");   //(NULL, "_,.-")//}
printf("Character \"%s\"\n", token);
token = strtok (NULL, "\n , ;");   //(NULL, "_,.-")
printf("Character 2 \"%s\"\n", token);
token = strtok (NULL, "\n , ;");   //(NULL, "_,.-")
printf("Comentaries \"%s\"\n",token);
token = strtok (NULL, ";");
//            printf("Character 2\"%s\"\n", token);
//           token = strtok (NULL, "\n , ;");   //(NULL, "_,.-")
token = NULL;}
//token = NULL;
//printf("Comentaries \"%s\"\n", token);
//token = NULL;
return(0);
}
```

the // coments are all my failed attempts to try to make it work =(
Can someone help me please?

Comment: `char *token;
while (token != NULL)` seems wrong. There's no guarantee that `token` will be initialized to non-NULL.

Comment: How should the parser know that 'adda' isn't a label?

Answer (score 9):

```
char *token;
while (token != NULL){
```

where is `token` initialized?

Then:

```
if (delimiter != "\n"||"\t")
```

You are only comparing pointers in the `if` controlling expression: use `strcmp` function to compare strings.

Comment: That's also not how `||` works.  You need to explicitly compare `delimiter` to each one.

Comment: i alrady tried to use strcmp but i think im not using it correctly because it only compares the full string when i just want to compare the delimeter or a token separetly

Answer (score 0):

I could see various problems with your code, as listed below:

1.Your while loop is based on `token` which is not initialized. Better use a `do/while`.

2.`delimiter` is a string and cannot be compared using `!=` operator. Use `strcmp/strncmp`.

3.What is the point of checking delimiter in every iteration when it is the assigned the same value everytime? I am not sure what are you trying to achieve by doing that. AFAIK, the value of `delimiter` is not changed on a call to `strtok`.

4.`token` should pass through a NULL check before every call to `strtok` as you area allowed to enter a "wrong" string.

5.Nothing wrong with it, but why exactly was `fgets` used for taking input from stdin, when you could simply do a `scanf`?

Hope above solves your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i made the corrections in my code acording to your advice, I changed my while to a do while, I tried to use strcmp but since I dotn know how to save my tokens to a separate string  so that I could use strcmp I don’t know how else could I use it,as when you said a NULL check what do you mean like i would have to use a if-statemnt to check if my delimeter is null or my strtok? And for the last I tried using a scanf but it dint worked properly when I wanted to check if the first character was a “space/s” or “Tab/s”

Comment: 1) you could use `strcpy` to copy strings. 2) you have to do a NULL check to the pointer `token` (`if (token != NULL)`) after every call to `strtok` to make sure whether your string is finished.